# What is the order of Print Out about NEW Keyword in Inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, upcasting

It's actually part of one interview question I got confused.

```
class A
{
   public A()
   {
        System.out.println("A") ;
    }
 }

 class B extends A
 {
     public B()
     {
         System.out.println("B") ;
     }
 }


 A a1 = new B();
 System.out.println() ;
 A a2 = (A) new B() ;
```

So the question is what is the print out?

At first I thought it should print out like

```
B
A

B
A
```

But after I run at home, it gives

```
A
B

A
B
```

I understand it's inheritance and then upcasting B to A, and it's legal syntax as well, but why is A print before B?

Comment: I would expect this if the constructor was `super(); System.out.println("B");` but now I am confused.

Comment: @Gendarme: Without any explicit `super(...)` or `this(...)`, the `super()` is implicit.

Comment: The super class must always be initialised first.

Answer (score 7):

> why is A print before B?

Because the body of the superclass constructor is executed before the body of the subclass constructor, basically.

Think of your `B()` constructor as implicitly:

```
public B()
{
    super(); // This invokes A's constructor
    System.out.println("B") ;
}
```

The full details are in [JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5). In particular:

> This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using `this`). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using `super`). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps.

Comment: Would this also happen if it was `B b1 = new B();`? Casting to `A` is totally irrelevant?

Comment: @Gendarme: Yup, totally irrelevant. It's just "the process of creating a new instance of B".

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of the parent class `A` is called before that of the subclass `B`. In other words, it is equivalent to:

```
public B() {
    super();
    System.out.println("B");
}
```